# Is a random variable taking every rational number or a range of rational numbers discrete or continuous?

Tags: continuous-data, discrete-data, definition

My guess would be discrete because such a variable would only take a countable set of values and "continuous" seems to imply the continuum of the real numbers.

Comment: It won't count as continuous, since you have points with non-zero probability. Whether it counts as discrete or not depends on exactly whose definition of discrete you use (there are other possibilities than discrete/continuous). By the definition I was taught, the answer is "yes that's discrete", but by another common definition the answer is "no". This doesn't change anything material other than the label we apply of course.

Comment: A great answer specifying exactly what the pmf of such a random variable might look like is [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/104018/6633)

Comment: These are both very helpful, clear responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A continuous variable has positive length, area or volume. These terms, respectively, correspond to particular Lebesgue measures. But the Lebesgue measure of $\mathbb{Q}$ is 0; it doesn't have positive length.

Approached from another perspective, it is sufficient to note that $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, so it's not continuous.