# What is the value of the probability mass of a rational random variable talking the value of any rational number in a given range

Tags: probability

[The first comment under the question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/173406/is-a-random-variable-taking-every-rational-number-or-a-range-of-rational-numbers) says it has 'non-zero probability'. I don't see how that is the case, as 1 divided by countable infinity should still be 0, which is same in value as 1 divided by uncountable infinity. Also I think the conclusion should be the same regardless of whether its domain is a finite interval or not.

Comment: Beware of working with and reasoning about infinities as if they were finite numbers.  A concrete example of such a random variable might help you out: see our thread at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/103969.

Comment: You cannot have a uniform distribution over a countably infinite set, so there is no need to think about "1 divided by countable infinity"

Comment: @Henry so the probability mass is zero everywhere right?

Comment: @Sam, a uniform distribution over a countably infinite set cannot exist, so it is difficult to talk about a probability mass or probability density of something which is not.  If a measure of each point in the set  were a constant $m$ then you would get a total of $\sum m=\infty$ if $m$ is positive or $\sum m=0$ if $m$ is zero (or perhaps $\sum m=-\infty$ if you allowed $m$ negative), so this would not be a probability measure where you need $\sum m=1$.  No division required.