# How to obtain an equivalent standard normal variate for a discrete distribution?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, pit

Let's say we have a continuous random variable with distribution function $F$. If we want to obtain a corresponding normal variate at $x$, then we simply compute $ \Phi ^ {-1 } \left(F  \left( x \right) \right)  $.

However, for a discrete distribution like a Poisson, I was told to obtain an equivalent normal distribution as  $ \Phi ^ {-1 } \left(z \right)  $ where $z$ is a random draw from a uniform distribution with range $ F  \left( x - 1 \right)$ and $ F  \left( x \right).$

Is this a correct approach? If yes, what is the theoretical basis for it? Any pointer and/or online resource will be very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This result becomes clear from a picture of the *inverse* of the operation described in the question.

[image: Figure showing a graph of a non-continuous CDF]

**Explanation**

$P$ is a uniform random variable supported on $(0,1):$ that is, it's a random probability.  "Uniform" means the chance that $P$ is less than any given $p$ (between $0$ and $1$) is $p$ itself.

**The percentage point function**

Given any value of $P,$ use it to locate a height on the vertical (probability) axis and read across the plot to the first (leftmost) point on the graph of $F$ you encounter.  Drop down, as shown by the arrows, to the value $X(P).$  Because $P$ is random, $X(P)$ is a random variable.

(Technical remark: the graph of any distribution function is automatically measurable, so we don't even have to check this condition.)

The mapping $P \to X(P)$ is sometimes called the *percentage point function,* written $X = F^{-1}(P).$  It is also called an *inverse cumulative distribution function* or a "left inverse" of $F,$ because $F^{-1}(F(x)) = x$ for all $x$ in the support of $F.$

**A formal statement the graphical procedure**

In this example the distribution $F$ assigns zero probability to the interval from $x=1$ to $x=2:$ its graph is horizontal there.  This is OK.  Many random variables have this behavior.  By choosing the leftmost point encountered, the graphical procedure will always select the *smallest* possible such $x$ in these intervals.  Mathematically this is written

$$X(P) = F^{-1}(P) = \inf\,\{x\mid F(x) \ge P\}.$$

**Why the percentage point function works**

The distribution of $X(P)$ is given by $F$ because--as I hope is evident from the figure--the chance that $X(P)$ is less than or equal to any specified number $x$ is the chance that $P$ is less than or equal to $F(x),$ equal to $F(x)$ because $P$ is uniform.  In symbols,

$$\Pr(X(P) \le x) = \Pr(P \le F(x)) = F(x).$$

Now, because $P$ has a uniform distribution on $(0,1),$ it has a uniform distribution when restricted to any (measurable) subset of $(0,1),$ such as the vertical interval shown in the plot between the red ticks on the probability axis.  This interval marks the jump at $X(P).$  It extends between the two possible limiting values of $F$ as $x \to X(P).$  *$P,$ restricted to this interval, is precisely the uniform random variable described in the question.*

In other words,

> **the construction in the question recreates $P$ by choosing $X$ according to the distribution $F$ and, if $F$ has a jump at $X,$ selecting a random height somewhere within the span of that jump.**

If $F$ does not jump at $X,$ we may take $P = F(X).$

**The answer to the question**

I chose to plot a distribution function that is neither discrete nor continuous, in order to make another point.  At any location $x$ where $F$ has no jump--that is, at its points of continuity--there is only one corresponding value of $P$ for which $X(P)=x.$  In this case the interval is the "degenerate" interval $[X(P), X(P)]$ and $P$ is constant on this interval.  Nevertheless--as I hope is evident--the construction still works.

Because of this, we may view the random variable $Z(P) = \Phi^{-1}(P)$ in exactly the same way, substituting $\Phi$ for $F.$  Since $P$ is uniform, $Z$ must have $\Phi$ for its distribution function, *QED.*

---

Going in the other direction from the random variable $X(P)$ (with distribution $F$) to the uniform random variable $P$ is called the [probability integral transform](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=probability+integral+transform) of $X.$

Comment: Many thanks for this explanation. But looks like I still not able to grasp the insight of drawing a random number. Lets take an example if `X = bin(10, 0.40)`, and `x = 3`. In this case, why I need to draw a number from `uniform` with range `P[X <= 2]` and `P[X <= 3]`? Cant I just get  `P[X <= 3]`?

Comment: If you just draw a random value $X$ from a discrete distribution, then there is no way you can produce a continuously distributed variable.  Each value of $X$ has a positive probability whereas in a continuous distribution, *no* value has a positive probability.

Comment: I don't understand that comment.  It might help to know that not all discrete variables are supported on the integers, whereas your question seems to assume that's the case.  An interesting example of a discrete distribution is given at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/103969.  Another example would be to let $X/\pi$ have a Poisson distribution, so that $X$ has *zero* probability of being an integer (it can only be a multiple of $\pi$).