Drawing uniformly from a skewed distribution
Are there methods to draw samples from a skewed population in such a way that the samples are uniformly distributed?
For example, if I want to show a correlation between height and salary, but the population is predominantly short, the heat map will appear skewed and won't be informative.
Is this a bad practice?

See our threads about the probability integral transform, or "PIT."  If your distribution is not continuous, see my post at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/579142/919 for how to apply the PIT anyway.

whuber answered your first question (how to do it); the links provided should show you how (basically inverse the eCDF of your sample). Now the 2nd question; is it bad practice? In your case (to "unskew" a skewed dataset), it would absolutely seem to be (bad practice). The now uniform dataset you will generate will no longer be representative of your population of interest, and the inferences you derive from the transformed dataset will not apply to the original population. UNless you can clarify what you intend to do with the transformed dataset, it does not seem like a good idea...

Taking your example: if you know height information already, you can use a stratified sampling method. Stratification splits the population into mutually exclusive groups (e.g. you might define strata of "<130cm", "131-145cm", etc.)
You can then use custom sampling fractions within each group to make sure you have coverage over the entire height range.
This will be an unequal probability sampling method, meaning you cannot treat it as a simple random sample. If you used this method to estimate average height without accounting for the sampling fractions, you will get a biased answer. However, it will provide a useful dataset for studying your trend of interest (height versus salary in your example).
This won't work unless you know the height information beforehand.
Re "the heat map will appear skewed and won't be informative.", I'm not sure I agree with this. If there is a correlation between height and salary, but your population is predominantly short, then I would example a simple random sample to also be predominantly short. This isn't "skewed", it just is what it is. The correlation plot will probably just show no relationship. I am not sure what the heat map is referring to.
