CDF of a discrete random variable piecewise-constant?
In my script, it says:

Given $X$ is a discrete random variable, $\Bbb P(X\in D)=1,D=\{a_1,a_2,\ldots\},p_i:=\Bbb P_X(\{a_i\})>0,\forall i\ge1,$ we have $F_X(x)=\sum\limits_{a_i\le x}p_i,$ which implies the CDF of a discrete random variable is piecewise-constant.

My thoughts
Suppose $X:\Omega\to\Bbb R$ is a discrete random variable with $\Bbb P_X(\{q_i\})=\frac1{2^i}>0,$ where $\{q_i\}_{i\in\Bbb N}$ is an enumeration of $\Bbb Q.$ Since $\Bbb Q$ is dense, for every two $x_1,x_2\in\Bbb R,x_1<x_2,$ there is some $q_j\in(x_1,x_2)$ implying $F_X(x_1)<F_X(x_2).$ So, it seems to contradict the statement that $F_X$ is piecewise-constant, leading me to wonder if my random variable $X$ even exists if the statement actually holds true.
Question: Is the CDF of any discrete random variable indeed piecewise-constant?

Because I cannot find a fully correct definition of "discrete random variable" on the Web (at least in the first several pages of Google hits), let me offer one here.
There does appear consensus about the underlying concept, generally characterized as "takes on at most a countable number of values."  But that misses some key concepts, so let's fall back to a rigorous setting.
Recall that a (real-valued) random variable is a measurable function on a probability space,
$$X:(\Omega,\mathfrak F, \mathbb P)\to(\mathbb R, \mathfrak B, \mathrm{d}\lambda)$$
where the codomain is the usual Lebesgue measure on the real numbers.  As a running example, let $\Omega=\mathbb R,$ let $\mathfrak F = 2^\Omega$ be the set of all subsets of numbers, let $(a_n), n=0,1,2,\ldots$ be any sequence of numbers, and let $(p_n),n=0,1,2,\ldots$ be any sequence of positive numbers summing to $1.$  Define the probability measure on any event $\mathcal E\in \mathfrak F$ to be the sum of the $p_n$ for all $a_n$ contained in $\mathcal E:$
$$\mathbb P(\mathcal E) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathcal I(a_n\in E)p_n = \sum_{n\mid a_n\in \mathcal E}p_n.$$
Because every subset is an event, any real-valued function $X$ defined on $\Omega$ is a random variable (no matter what $\mathfrak B$ and $\mathrm d\lambda$ might be, by the way).  In particular, let $X$ be the identity, $X(x)=x.$ The possible values of this random variable are all the real numbers, which are uncountable.
According to almost all the "definitions" I can find, this random variable is not discrete.  But that's a problem, because if we were to take $a_n=n$ and $p_n = q^n/(1-q)$ for some $0\lt q\lt 1,$ $X$ would have a Geometric distribution; or if $p_n = e^{-\mu}\mu^n/n!$ for some $\mu \gt 0$ we would have a Poisson distribution--and everybody agrees these are discrete distributions.  It would be terrible for discrete variables not to have discrete distributions!
These considerations provide several insights:


The definition of "discrete random variable" must refer both to the variable (as a function) and to the underlying probability measure.

Definitions of "discrete random variable" and "discrete distribution" ought to be compatible in the sense that every discrete random variable has a discrete distribution and every discrete distribution arises from a discrete random variable.

These definitions do not need to refer to, use, or appeal to any topological properties of the real numbers--or, indeed, any of their properties whatsoever!  The role of $\mathbb R$ is that of a set without any additional structure.



One set of definitions that meets these criteria is the following.

A random variable $X$ is discrete when there exists an at most countable set of real numbers $x_0,x_1,x_2,\ldots$ for which $\Pr(X=x_0)+\Pr(X=x_1)+\Pr(X=x_2)+\cdots = 1.$
A distribution (on the real numbers) is discrete when it is the distribution of a discrete random variable.

When this is the case, we say

The support of a discrete random variable $X$ is the set of numbers $x$ for which $\Pr(X=x)\ne 0.$  (In the example above, the support therefore is a subset of $\{a_n, n = 0, 1, 2, \ldots\}.$)

These definitions are comprehensive in that any variable or distribution generally considered discrete is discrete according to these definitions.  But the present definitions comprise interesting examples, such as the first example above (all real numbers are possible values of $X$) and the one at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/104018/919.  That post constructs a discrete random variable whose support is an interval of rational numbers $[0,1]\cap\mathbb Q,$ which is dense within the interval $[0,1]$ of real numbers.
In fact, it's easy and instructive to construct discrete random variables whose supports are any subset of $\mathbb Q$ you please.  Let $\mathcal A\subseteq \mathbb Q$ be such a subset.  Because $\mathbb Q$ is countable, so is $\mathcal A,$ so write $\mathcal A = \{a_0, a_1, a_2, \ldots\}.$ Let $p_n$ be a sequence of positive probabilities summing to $1,$ such as $p_n = 2^{-(n+1)},n=0,1,2,\ldots$ when $\mathcal A$ is infinite.  The support of the random variable $X$ constructed from the sequences $(a_n)$ and $(p_n)$ in the running example is precisely $\mathcal A.$  Conversely, any random variable whose support is $\mathcal A$ can be constructed in this fashion (although the construction is not unique).

Finally, let's address the question. A "piecewise constant" function $F:\mathbb R\to [0,1]$ can be defined as one that is almost everywhere constant.  That is, let's call a number $x$ a "bad point" if there does not exist any open interval $\mathcal U$ with $x\in\mathcal U$ on which $F$ is constant.  A constant function is one with no bad points.  A piecewise constant function has at most a countable number of bad points.  (An intermediate concept is one in which all bad points are isolated: that is, around each bad point $x$ there is some open interval $\mathcal U$ with $x\in \mathcal U$ being the only bad point in $\mathcal U.$)
Because $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R,$ the distribution function $F_X$ for any $X$ with $\mathbb Q$ as its support is not piecewise constant: this is a counterexample to the claim in the question.
However, if we adopt the more restrictive intermediate concept involving isolated bad points, the claim can be made true:

The distribution function of any random variable $X$ with isolated support is piecewise constant and conversely, piecewise constant distribution functions $F_X$ are distributions of discrete variables.

This is essentially tautological, following from the definitions.

I think your answer addressed what I was looking for. I'll go through the linked post carefully.

The issue here is that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense, which is unusual for the kinds of discrete distributions we deal with most commonly in statistical practice.  Since a random variable/distribution is usually considered to be discrete if it has countable support, my view is that you are correct that the stipulated random variable is a "discrete random variable" with a "discrete distribution" and it provides a counter-example to the asserted piecewise-constancy result.  Here is a weaker piecewise-constancy theorem that is true:

Theorem: If $X: \mathcal{S} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a discrete random variable with support $\mathscr{X} \subset \mathbb{R}$ that is nowhere dense then its cumulative distribution function $F_X$ is piecewise-constant.
Proof: Consider an arbitrary point $x \notin \mathscr{X}$.  Since $\mathscr{X}$ is nowhere dense in $\mathbb{R}$ we can form a neighbourhood $\mathscr{E} \ni x$ with $\mathscr{E} \cap \mathscr{X} = \varnothing$.  Over this set we have:
$$F_X(x) = \sum_{r \in \mathscr{H}(\mathscr{E})} \mathbb{P}(X=r)
\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad 
\text{for all } x \in \mathscr{E}.$$
where $\mathscr{H}(\mathscr{E}) \equiv \{ x \in \mathscr{X} | x \leqslant \inf \mathscr{E} \}$ is the subset of the support containing values below the values in $\mathscr{E}$.  This cumulative probability is fixed over the neighbourhood of $x$ so the CDF is constant over this neighbourhood .  Since this is true at every point not in the support, and since the support is countable, it follows that $F_X$ is piecewise-constant over $\mathbb{R}$.  $\blacksquare$

Wikipedia agrees with the OP that the random variable that the OP has constructed does not have a distribution function that is piecewise constant.
With regard to the OP's question "Is the CDF of any discrete random variable indeed piecewise-constant?", the answer is Yes if the question means "Do there exist any discrete random variables at all  whose CDFs are piecewise constant?" (most commonly encountered discrete random variables, e.g. binomial, geometric, Poisson etc are of this type) and NO if the question means "Is the CDF of every discrete random variable a piecewise-constant function?" and the example that the OP has constructed is a counterexample to the proposed claim. Another counterexample is in this answer by Moderator whuber.
I propose a new definition: A definitely discrete random variable is a discrete random variable such that every finite-length interval contains at most a finite number of values of the discrete random variable.
A definitely discrete random variable has the property that the CDF is piecewise constant; in fact a staircase function with risers of heights $p_i$ at points $a_i$ and having constant value on each step $[a_i,a_{i+1})$. So, all the OP needs to do is include this definition in the "script" being read, and then  modify the script to say "Given that $X$ is a definitely discrete random variable, $\ldots$"

Thank you very much! It seems our definition of a discrete random variable was different because we only required the existence of a finite or a countable $D\subset\Bbb R$ s. t. $\Bbb P(X\in D)=1$ and $\Bbb Q$ isn't well-ordered.

This answer looks exactly wrong, because the example in the question contradicts it.  Countable denumerability is not equivalent to such a linear ordering!  I suspect the prompt in the question is derived from a limited (but common) definition of "discrete" as meaning supported on a lattice, or at least for which the support has no accumulation points.

@whuber I was answering the question "Is there any discrete random variable for which the CDF is piecewise constant?" and provided as an answer a whole subclass of discrete random variables: those discrete random variables whose values can be linearly ordered. I never claimed that every discrete random variable has this property, since, as you say, the example in the OP's question is a counterexample. I believe that you yourself once wrote an answer on stats.SE fleshing out the details of a discrete random variable taking on a countably infinite number of values in $\mathbb Q$.

"... can be linearly ordered ..." strikes me as an unusual definition (or even characterization) of a discrete variable: that's what is tripping me up.  Would you perhaps have a reference for that?  (The post you remember is likely https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/104018/919.)

@whuber I have never claimed that the linear ordering is part of the definition of a discrete random variable, or even a characterization of all discrete random variables. All I am saying is that there is a subclass of the set of all discrete random variables such that the values can be linearly ordered, and for all random variables in this subclass, the CDF is a staircase function. The subclass incudes all discrete random variables that take on a finite number of values, as well as geometric, negative binomial, Poisson random variables that take on countably infinite numbers of values.

I'm sorry, but the phrase "Any random variable taking on values that are discrete, that is, we can enumerate the values as ... < ... < ..." explicitly is such a claim.  I suggest rephrasing that so people will understand what you intended.

Re the edit: it is interesting that a variable such as $-1/(1+X),$ where $X$ has a Poisson distribution, is not "definitely discrete" (because any open interval including $0$ contains infinitely many elements of the support), yet its distribution function is piecewise constant (because it is constant on countably many intervals $[0,\infty),$ $(-\infty,-1),$ $[-1,-1/2),$ $[-1/2,-1/3),\ldots$ and the union of those intervals is $\mathbb R$). This suggests that "definitely discrete" doesn't fully capture the underlying concept explored in the question.
